# Strange 404 error when loading Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I set up a Leaflet map on our server with several layers tiled by the leaflet-geojson-vt plugin. On my local machine everything runs fine, but as soon as I start it up from the server and click on a marker, the console starts printing 404 errors.

[image: error console]

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here. I'd like to provide you the link to the server running it currently:
https://wasserwiki.eu/Wasserwiki_App_Mobile/#47.89246,12.4509,11z

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code in the body of the question, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but the Datensatz.js and Deutschland.js lack the proper encoding. The Umlaute are displayed mangled in my browser (both in the JS files and in the leaflet popups).

Answer (score 1):

The img tags you write in your HTML document on line 289

```
"<img src='"+ feature.properties.Bildlink +"'width='300'</img>" +"<br>"+"<br>"+
```

are not formatted correctly.

Change it to

```
"<img src='"+ feature.properties.Bildlink +"' width='300'></img>" +"<br>"+"<br>"+
```

(add ">" after width='300' and space before width) and see if it helps.

edit: it may be that particular function is not used anywhere. **Please** provide a minimal example to show your error. It really is very difficult to help you if you don't provide the code that throws the error (not more than 10-20 lines).